# Intercept in linear regression

Tags: scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am new to machine learning and I am confused with what is the function of linear regression intercept parameter is doing.

When setting the parameter, `fit_intercept=False`, I get the `.coef`_ value as **287.986236**, however, when setting `fit_intercept=True`, I get the `.coef`_ value as **225.81285046**.

Why is there a difference? And I am not sure how to interpret the results and compare these values!

```py
    lm = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False).fit(REStaten_[['GROSS_SQUARE_FEET']], REStaten_['SALE_PRICE'])
    lm.coef_
    # 287.986236

    lm = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=True).fit(REStaten_[['GROSS_SQUARE_FEET']], REStaten_['SALE_PRICE'])
    lm.coef_
    # 225.81285046
```

Comment: look [this] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46779605/in-the-linearregression-method-in-sklearn-what-exactly-is-the-fit-intercept-par)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In the LinearRegression method in sklearn, what exactly is the fit\_intercept parameter doing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46779605/in-the-linearregression-method-in-sklearn-what-exactly-is-the-fit-intercept-par)

Answer (score 0):

- The **Slope** and **Intercept** are the very important concept of Linear regression.
- The **slope** indicates the steepness of a line and the **intercept** indicates the location where it intersects an axis.
- If we set the Intercept as False then, no intercept will be used in calculations (e.g. data is expected to be already centered).

When we are using LR model in a dataset, It is trying to plot the "Line of best fit" by increasing or decreasing the **Slope** and  **Intercept** values.
You are getting different .coef_ values because you are disabling the **Intercept** parameter in your first attempt and enabling it on your second attempt.

Hope this helps. For more info, you can refer the scikit-learn documentation.
[Sk Learn Linear regression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html)