# linear regression with a forced non-zero y-intercept

Tags: python, linear-regression

I would like to run a linear regression with the y-intercept forced to 0.115. This is the code I tried. I set to fit_intercept=True to get a non-zero y-intercept, but can I set it to a value?

Also, how can I get the best fit line to be plotted rather than a line connecting each point?

Thanks in advance.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
x=np.array([0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]).reshape(-1,1)
y=np.array([0.113, 0.116, 0.130, 0.150, 0.150, 0.160, 0.180, 0.210, 0.220, 0.260, 0.280])
regression=LinearRegression(fit_intercept=True).fit(x,y)
r_sq=round(regression.score(x,y),4)
m=round(regression.coef_[0],4)
b=round(regression.intercept_,4)
print("r_sq:", r_sq,"m:",m,"b:",b)
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.title('A')
plt.ylabel('X')
plt.xlabel('Y')
plt.plot(x,y,'r--',label='measured')
plt.legend(loc='best')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subtract the y intercept you want to fix from your data and set `fit_intercept=False`.

For example

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

x = np.array([0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]).reshape(-1, 1)
y = np.array([0.113, 0.116, 0.130, 0.150, 0.150, 0.160, 0.180, 0.210, 0.220, 0.260, 0.280])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for fit, y_intercept in zip((True, False), (0.0, 0.115)):
    regression = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=fit)
    regression.fit(x, y - y_intercept)

    r_sq = regression.score(x, y - y_intercept)
    m = regression.coef_[0]
    b = regression.intercept_ + y_intercept

    print(f"Fit intercept: {regression.fit_intercept}")
    print(f"r_sq: {r_sq:0.4f}\nm: {m:0.4f}\nb: {b:0.4f}")

    ax.plot(x, y, "bo")
    ax.plot(
        x,
        regression.predict(x) + y_intercept,
        "r" + "--" * fit,
        label=f"Fit Intercept: {regression.fit_intercept}",
    )

ax.set_title("A")
ax.set_ylabel("X")
ax.set_xlabel("Y")

ax.legend(loc="best")

plt.show()
```

Which prints:

```
Fit intercept: True
r_sq: 0.9473
m: 0.0017
b: -0.0192
Fit intercept: False
r_sq: 0.9112
m: 0.0014
b: 0.0000
```

Comment: The results does not match what I get from Excel. I get:
     r_sq: -3.1784 m: 0.0014 b: 0.0

Comment: However, from Excel, the results are r-squared=0.9473, the slope is 0.0014 (which matches), and the y-intercept is 0.115 as forced. I changed to "r_sq=round(regression.score(x,y-y_intercept),4)" but the r-squared still does not match. I get 0.9112 rather than 0.9473. Do I need to change any other parameters?

Comment: I've updated my answer, take a look. When you fit the intercept you get the same R^2 value as excel. I don't know what Excel is doing under the hood, but I played around: you can set the intercept to _any_ non-zero value and it'll return the *same* R^2 value. Looks like a bug in Excel to me.

Comment: It works and it does seem Excel is giving the same R^2 values for both, so probably a bug. The data I get is a little different, but it is from a copy and paste of your code, and it matches the results from Excel except for the R^2 value for the "Fit intercept: False" case.
Fit intercept: True
r_sq: 0.9473
m: 0.0017
b: 0.0958
Fit intercept: False
r_sq: 0.9112
m: 0.0014
b: 0.1150

Answer (score 1):

I found a general solution which gave me the same answer, but also allows me to fit equations that are not linear by simply modifying the function.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np

#set y-intercept
b=0.115

#Fitting function
def func(x, m):
    return (x*m)+b

#Experimental x and y data points    
x_A1 = np.array([0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100])
y_A1 = np.array([0.113, 0.116, 0.130, 0.150, 0.150, 0.160, 0.180, 0.210, 0.220, 0.260, 0.280])

#Plot experimental data points
plt.plot(x_A1, y_A1, 'bo', label='experimental')

#Perform the curve-fit
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x_A1, y_A1) #, initialGuess)
#print(popt)

#x values for the fitted function
x_A1_Fit = np.arange(x_A1[0], x_A1[-1], 0.1)

residuals = y_A1- func(x_A1, *popt)
ss_res = np.sum(residuals**2)
ss_tot = np.sum((y_A1-np.mean(y_A1))**2)
r_sq = 1 - (ss_res / ss_tot)

#Plot the fitted function
plt.plot(x_A1_Fit, func(x_A1_Fit, *popt), 'r--', label='fitted: m=%5.4f' % tuple(popt))

plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
print ('r_sq=', "%.4f"%r_sq, 'm=', "%.4f"%popt, "b=", "%.4f"%b)
```

Answer (score 0):

A  post on fit_intercept https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46779605

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

x=np.array([0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]).reshape(-1,1)
y=np.array([0.113, 0.116, 0.130, 0.150, 0.150, 0.160, 0.180, 0.210, 0.220, 0.260, 0.280])

lr_fi_true = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=True)
lr_fi_false = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False)

lr_fi_true.fit(x, y)
lr_fi_false.fit(x, y)

print('Intercept when fit_intercept=True : {:.5f}'.format(lr_fi_true.intercept_))
print('Intercept when fit_intercept=False : {:.5f}'.format(lr_fi_false.intercept_))

lr_fi_true_yhat = np.dot(x, lr_fi_true.coef_) + lr_fi_true.intercept_
lr_fi_false_yhat = np.dot(x, lr_fi_false.coef_) + lr_fi_false.intercept_

plt.scatter(x, y, label='Actual points')
plt.plot(x, lr_fi_true_yhat, 'r--', label='fit_intercept=True')
plt.plot(x, lr_fi_false_yhat, 'r-', label='fit_intercept=False')
plt.legend()

plt.vlines(0, 0, y.max())
plt.hlines(0, x.min(), x.max())

plt.show()
```

Prints:

```
Intercept when fit_intercept=True : 0.09577
Intercept when fit_intercept=False : 0.00000
```

[image]

Comment: This answer fixes the plot and the answer above provides how to force a non-zero y-intercept.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using NumPy's linear algebra library and specifically the pseudo-inverse function `np.linalg.pinv`. This approach allows you use only the NumPy package as shown below.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]).reshape(-1,1)
y = np.array([0.113, 0.116, 0.130, 0.150, 0.150, 0.160, 0.180, 0.210, 0.220, 0.260, 0.280])

b    =  0.115        # fixed intercept
a    =  np.linalg.pinv( x ) @ (y - b)  # estimated slope
yfit = (a * x) + b   # fitted y values


plt.figure()
plt.scatter(x, y, label='data')
plt.plot(x, yfit, label='fit')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

[image: regression with forced intercept]